# Javascript onclick with base tag in ie with subfolder

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, onclick, radix

Try this: create a folder `test` in your website, and put this html file (`test.html`) in it:

```
<html><head>
<base href="http://www.site.com/" />
</head><body>
<span onclick="window.location.href='test/test.html?done!';return false;">click me</span>
</body></html>
```

Click the link in your favourite browser. What's the URL?

Click the link in IE. What's the URL?

EDIT: IE takes you to: http://www.site.com/test/test/test.html?done!

Any way to fix this, that isn't (1) removing base tag, (2) changing onclick to use a function that appends the proper base? Is there a way to override the window.location.href function in IE?

Comment: I would probably try to answer this if you said what you were seeing, instead of making me try it out. Rhetorical questions are memorable but not very transparent.

Comment: IE takes you to: `http://www.site.com/test/test/test.html?done!`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After moving my `test.htm` into a subdirectory called `test` (final relative path: `test/test.htm`), I am able to confirm the bug (I initially misunderstood what you were asking about). [Googling it also confirms that it is a bug](https://www.google.com/search?q=Internet%20Explorer%20ignores%20base%20tag), or at the very least a non-Standard implementation of the `<base>` tag (this may merely be *yet another case* of Microsoft not following implementations according to specification).

IE will honor the `<base>` tag for any defined anchors.

```
<a href="test/test.html">Click me</span>
```

will go to `http://www.site.com/test/test.html` (provided the `<base>` tag is either not closed, or not self-closed for older versions of IE), but IE (all versions) will only honor the base tag for anchors, not for JavaScript.

The reason IE prepends the additional `test/` to your URL is actually standards-compliant behavior. As IE is ignoring the `<base>` tag, your link of `test/test.html` indicates that there is a subdirectory called `test` with a `test.html` file relative to the current directory (`test`) and IE correctly navigates to `test/test/test.html'.

As far as how to fix it...

1. Removing the `<base>` tag will not help.
2. Changing the `onclick` to a function that returns the correct base URL would work, but you've stated this is not acceptable.
3. `window.location.href` is a String, not a function, so "overriding" it is a non-starter.
4. Changing `onclick` to use an absolute URL would also work.
5. Removing all embedded `onclick` attributes and assigning them via JavaScript (`attachEvent` or `addEventListener`) would be more effective in the long run (separation of content/behavior) and allow you to easily attach the correct base URL (and the method I would probably choose, although I don't know your specific circumstance).
6. You could use a DOM manipulation library, like jQuery/Dojo/Prototype to loop through any `onclick` attributes and update the URL to an absolute URL.

Comment: Hi Pete. There shouldn't be a file `C:\Users\Pete\Desktop\test.html`. The `test.html` file should only exist in the folder, `test` (also, there's only 1 html file, not `test.htm` and `test.html`). In my real application, I have a folder `reports`. In that folder, I have a Default page, which lists & links to all the reports pages, with relative urls and the base tag, like `reports\report1.html`. If I use `<a href='reports\report1.html'>`, the `base` tag is honoured. But if I use a javascript onlick location.href, it fails because it attempts to go to `\reports\reports\report1.html`.

Comment: @SeanW: Bug confirmed. Updated answer.

Comment: Thanks Pete. I've marked it as the answer, although it's not the answer I had wanted.

Answer (score 1):

This is apparently still an issue in IE11. I ran into it just now. What I've done is this:

```
onclick="window.location=document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0].href+'your_url_destination';"
```

It requires modifying the onclick line, but it doesn't require a separate function. It should work in all browsers, and has so far for me.